# Null values in Freemarker Template

Tags: freemarker

**Code**:

```
<if state??>
<ns1:StateName>${state}</ns1:StateName>
</#if>
```

I want to print the value when state is not null.

Getting this error:

```
Unexpected directive, "</#if>". Check if you have a valid #if-#elseif-#else structure.
```

Please help with the solution

Comment: Try with `<#if state??>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<#if state??>
<ns1:StateName>${state}</ns1:StateName>
</#if>
```